# Ionic open a link on click

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I was using [linky](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/filter/linky) to make link out of my content. All the content is dynamic. When i press the link nothing is happening. How can i make this link open the page in browser?

```
<p ng-bind-html="post.details | linky:'_blank'"></p>
```

Comment: are you missing the `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`?

Comment: yes i hv installed that already